# Date Range AngularJS Form validation

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, date

I have 2 date fields:  departure / arrival.

Both have validation on them using a directive.

Here is what the directive looks like for the "arrival" date range:

```
(function(angular) {
'use strict';

function dateRangeToValidatorDirective () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require : 'ngModel',
    link : function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        function validateToDateRange (value) {
            var valid = true;
            if (scope.$eval(attrs.dateRangeValue) && value) {
                var arrivalDate   = Date.parse(value);
                var departureDate = Date.parse(scope.$eval(attrs.dateRangeValue));
                valid = arrivalDate >= departureDate;
                if (valid) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('toDateRange', true);
                    ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('fromDateRange', true);  // Why doesn't this work?
                }
                else {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('toDateRange', false);
                }                   
            }
            return value;
        }
        ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(validateToDateRange);
    }
  }
}

angular
    .module('components.shared')
    .directive('dateRangeToValidator', dateRangeToValidatorDirective)

})(window.angular);
```

HTML usage:

```
<input type="text" name="arrivalDate" maxlength="10" required 
                         date-picker date-range-to-validator 
                         date-range-value="$ctrl.newFlight.departureDate"
                         placeholder='MM/DD/YYYY' 
                         ng-model="$ctrl.newFlight.arrivalDate" 
                         id="nf_arrivalDate" size="10" />

<div class="input-error" 
     ng-show="$ctrl.newFlight.departureDate.length &&                                                          
              $ctrl.newFlight.arrivalDate.length &&                                                        
              newFlight.arrivalDate.$dirty &&                                                            
              newFlight.arrivalDate.$invalid">
    Arrival Date cannot precede Departure Date!
</div>
```

The "departure" date range is the same with a few minor differences. 
(no need to fill up the screen with the same code)

This works except in the following use case(s):

Step 1. Set departure date: 12/28/2017

Step 2. Set arrival date: 12/27/2017

===> Error is shown "Arrival Date cannot precede Departure Date!"

Step 3. Modify departure date: 12/26/2017

Actual:  "Arrival Date" error message does not go away.

Expected: "Arrival Date" error message goes away.

Question:  How do I get one directive that is on one element to affect the $valid state of another element that is using another directive?

Please notice my comment in the `if (valid)` block where I am asking why doesn't this work?  If I set the validity of the model controller in one directive - why can't I get at the same model controller from another directive?  I assume that this is case because that isn't working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a couple of controller functions that would get invoked depending on the date field that changed using `ng-change`.  First I needed to expose the form to my controller; hence you will notice that my form name changed.  Once I could access the form from my controller, changing the validity of the element was easy.

```
function checkDepartureDate() {
    if (ctrl.newFlightForm.arrivalDate.$valid && 
        ctrl.newFlight.departureDate.length &&
        ctrl.newFlightForm.departureDate.$invalid) {
        ctrl.newFlightForm.departureDate.$setValidity("fromDateRange", true);
        }
    }
}

<input type="text"  name="arrivalDate" maxlength="10" required 
                          date-picker date-range-to-validator 
                          date-range-value="$ctrl.newFlight.departureDate"
                          placeholder='MM/DD/YYYY' 
                          ng-model="$ctrl.newFlight.arrivalDate"
                          ng-change="$ctrl.checkDepartureDate()" 
                          id="nf_arrivalDate" size="10" />
```